Approximation of integral of product of two functions
I am currently trying to derive the following approximation of integrals:
Suppose we have functions $\phi:\mathbb R^d\rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $f:\mathbb R^d\times \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$. For all intents and purposes they are "very nice functions". Now with setting $\xi = y-x$ I am looking at
\begin{align}
\int\limits_{\mathbb R^d} \phi(|x-y|)f(y,t)dy = f(x,t) + \frac{1}{2}\int\limits_\mathbb{R^d} \xi^ 2\phi(|\phi|)d\xi + \int\limits_\mathbb{R^d}\phi(|\xi|)O(\xi^4)d\xi
\end{align}
As a hint I have given the change of variables formula but no matter how I approach this I am nowhere near getting to this approximation. My analysis is a bit rusty though so any help would be appreciated.
